# Reference for solved exercises in additive combinatorics

Tags: reference-request, additive-combinatorics

I am aware that additive combinatorics is a relatively new subject and there are not many books available.

I will be grateful if anybody can tell me about some source where I can find a few solved exercises in this subject.

I have not found any book or course notes.

Thanks!

Comment: [Wikipedia has an entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_combinatorics)  with a reference to a book of Terence Tao and a link to a [review of this book](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2009-46-03/S0273-0979-09-01231-2/S0273-0979-09-01231-2.pdf)

Comment: @SARTHAKGUPTA:  FWIW, additive combinatorics is also known as *additive number theory*.  Perhaps you could try expanding your web search to include the latter phrase?

Comment: I taught a course on additive combinatorics this year, the page for which is at http://thomasbloom.org/teaching/ac2021.html. This page includes lecture notes, some exercises, and also links to other lecture notes/courses by other people.